# WSO2 IS API to get userclaim of a service provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Have figured out a way to get basic service provider information using rest API for WSO2 Identity Server.

```
https://localhost:9443/api/identity/oauth2/dcr/v1.1/register/{client_id}
```

And I got

```
{
    "client_name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "redirect_uris": [
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    ]
}
```

But this lacks any user claim information. I made the custom claims as mandatory.

Is there any way to get user claims registered for a particular service provider using a rest API call?

Answer (score 1):

`api/identity/oauth2/dcr` is the [standard OAuth DCR endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7591) and it is used to manage the OAuth client applications only. To view/update the other configurations of service providers you may use the SOAP admin service endpoint.

The service contract of this admin service can be found at `https://<IS_HOST>:<IS_PORT>/services/IdentityApplicationManagementService?wsdl`. Replace the tag `<IS_HOST>:<IS_PORT>` with the relevant host and port number, for example:  `https://localhost:9443/services/IdentityApplicationManagementService?wsdl`.

Find more information on [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Using+the+Service+Provider+API).